# Sync IO is unbelievably slower on newer Linux kernel

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel

I just find that sync IO is getting much much slower on newer kernels. I have tried the following commands on *CentoOs(2.6), Fedora20(3.11), Ubuntu12(3.2)*.

```
echo 0 > test
dd if=/dev/zero of=test bs=1024 count=200 oflag=dsync
```

The speed for 2.6 is about 1MB/s and only around 25kB/s for new kernels.

I have a CFD code which calls `sync()` in a C function. Usually the code runs very fast on old kernels, but now it is much slower on newer OS. I am really curious what the Linux developers have done to `sync()`. The other possible reason is not on kernel version, but the file system used by different OS.

At this point my code needs `sync()` anyway, so is there anything I can tune like `ioctl()` to speed it up?

Any comment is truly appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing that on the exact same hardware?

Comment: @wallyk while I have a CentOS virtual box running on Fedora20. Ubuntu12 is another guy's machine but with similar hardware. We captured the issue when we found that our CFD code is running slower on better hardware with newer OS, then we identified the problem is in sync().

Answer (score 2):

The apparent performance of `sync()` is greatly affected by the amount of memory installed in the system, the usage pattern of disk i/o (including the drive's caches, DMA controllers, etc.), and the speed of the disk drives.

Without rigorously controlling for all these variables, comparing one system to another is reasonably meaningless when you think you are changing only the kernel.

The effect of newer hardware seeming to make things slower makes sense.  Instead of the kernel flushing out pending writes when there is a 250 MB backlog (because the system only has 2 GB of RAM), it can now defer it to a 16 GB backlog because the newer system has 64 GB of RAM.

Comment: To solve the third paragraph problem set the vm.dirty_bytes to a value equal to about what your disk IO can flush in one second. Set vm.dirty_background_bytes to about half that.

Comment: @wallyk, thanks a lot for your answer. My own workstation runs Fedora20 and has 96G RAM, the virtual machine on it is CentOS with 4G RAM. So according to your description, the reason that sync() is slower is due to the large RAM size. I will create another virtual machine with exact the same configuration as the previous one, and install a newer OS, then I can do a more rigorous comparison. I will keep you posted.

Comment: @ZanLynx, thank you very much. I will try your method and let you know how it works.